# persistant functions on a jquery object

Tags: jquery

I know you can store stuff in a jQuery object using `.data()`, and whenever that element is found, regardless of the selector used, your data will be there.

You can also use `.sub()` to create branches of jQuery with your own functions and use that sub to select elements.

But is there a way to simply say `$("#something").foo = function() { ... };`, and then later go `$("#something").foo();`?

It doesn't seem like it would be that hard a plugin to write. And to me it seems that would be an awesome tool to have. Is there some reason I can't find it?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery objects aren't persistent which means a new jQuery object will be created each time you say $("#something"). That means, it actually goes and searched the Dom tree each time for a element where id=something.

If you want to add a function to that, you can just store the jQuery object in a variable and later on, reference that variable like this:

```
var something = $("#something");
something.foo = function() { ... }
// Later on
something.foo();
```

You can also really easily extend jQuery's behavior with your own plugin by saying,

```
jQuery.fn.foo = function() {

  // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

};
```

Then you can directly make a call like $("#something").foo();

Comment: Everything is ok, except the plugin part. The problem is that using a plugin would add the method to _all_ jquery instances, and nicholas wants to add a method to an specific instance.

Comment: Yeah, that much I understand. Though, both those approaches have drawbacks. Storing the variable isn't always easy. In a modular application you don't always want to be passing variables around, nor do you want to clutter some common (or global) namespace storing everything. Making a plugin doesn't really do it for me, because then EVERY time I create a jQuery object I get that function... I only want the function to exist on a specific element...

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, because everytime you use the `$` function, it creates a **new** jquery object, so you'd lose the added properties or methods.

```
$("#something").foo = function() { ... }
$("#something").foo(); //Error. foo is not a function
```

However, you could add this method directly to the dom element (but it's not recommended), like this:

```
$("#something")[0].foo = function() { ... };
$("#something")[0].foo(); //foo() gets executed!!
```

but you would have to be carefull, you could overwrite an existent dom method or property. For example, if you name your method 'innerHTML' you would overwrite that property. That's why it's not recommended.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Yeah, there's a name for applying a function directly to a dom node... I can't remember it off the top of my head, but I know it's a bad idea. But that's the functionality I'm looking for.